# WorkManager not working for Baidu Push SDK

Tags: android, android-workmanager, baidu

I am using **Baidu Push SDK** in my project. I created a broadcast receiver to receive Baidu notifications which extends **PushMessageReceiver**. Whenever a notification is received I perform a one-time work manager request to upload the event to our server. As the broadcast receiver runs in another process I get below exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
```

Can someone please help me with the solution to perform my WorkManager request successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WorkManager is failing because Baidu Push works on a different process and WorkManager is not initialized in Baidu's process. You need to do two things, first, initialize WorkManager by wrapping it inside the condition which checks if the application is in the main process. It will avoid the WorkManager error you get. Second, you need to create a custom BroadcastReceiver to which you will be sending broadcasts when you get a notification in Baidu's BroadcastReceiver.

Hope this will solve your problem.